# Why do I get no project listing when I attempt to create a BigQuery table?

Tags: google-bigquery

On BigQuery I get a results file of 175,000 rows.  When trying to download I get an error message that the file is too large to create a csv file.  It says to create a BigQuery table and export the data.

When I click on the option it takes me to a dialog box in which I am to click on Project and select one.  All I get for hours is the spinning circle.

Your advice is most appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just tested this and this worked for me:

- In Classic UI: Click on Save as Table -> (in dialog) select a project, a dataset, and a table -> Ok
- In Console UI: Click on Save Results -> Save results as table -> (in dialog) select a project, a dataset, and write a table -> Save

After this, you can export the created table. You can also [set the destination table for the query result](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#saving_query_results_to_a_table) and then the result will create/append to the destination table

Comment: Thanks.  I will reboot my machine and try again.

Comment: I tried rebooting and running again.  Same result.  When I get the dialog box and click on the Project field, I get the spinning circle.

Comment: Same thing if I try to specify the table destination in settings, before running the query.

Comment: I just checked this again and it works for me. My only guess is some permission issue (you may lack project.get permissions). However, I just checked this on my end and it gives Access Denied error instead of spinning circle. Have you checked that same issue happens in the Console UI? Since this seems to be related to your specific project, the best way is to contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) to review your project configuration.